# How to run .sh on Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, bash, command-line, sh

How can I run .sh on Windows 7 Command Prompt? I always get this error when I try to run this line in it,

```
app/build/build.sh
```

error,

```
'app' is not recognized...
```

or,

```
bash app/build/build.sh
```

error,

```
'bash' is not recognized...
```

Any ideas what have I missed?

Here the screen grab,
[image]

Comment: you need cygwin (possibly). You are trying to run SHELL (.sh) scripts on Windows and that's the only way I've run my `.sh` files on Windows.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The error message indicates that you have not installed `bash`, or it is not in your `PATH`.

The top Google hit is http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/ but you also need to understand that most Bash scripts expect a Unix-like environment; so just installing Bash is probably unlikely to allow you to run a script you found on the net, unless it was specifically designed for this particular usage scenario.  The usual solution to that is https://www.cygwin.com/ but there are many possible alternatives, depending on what exactly it is that you want to accomplish.

If Windows is not central to your usage scenario, installing a free OS (perhaps virtualized) might be the simplest way forward.

The second error message is due to the fact that Windows nominally accepts forward slash as a directory separator, but in this context, it is being interpreted as a switch separator.  In other words, Windows parses your command line as `app /build /build.sh` (or, to paraphrase with Unix option conventions, `app --build --build.sh`).  You could try `app\build\build.sh` but it is unlikely to work, because of the circumstances outlined above.

Comment: Of course, with Windows 10, you can enable WSL and almost have a real computer inside your Windows.

Answer (score 316):

Install [GIT](https://git-scm.com/downloads). During installation of GIT, add GIT Bash to windows context menu by selecting its option. After installation right click in your folder select `GIT Bash Here` (see attached pic) and use your sh command like for example:

```
sh test.sh
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me. A command prompt window opens then quickly closes.

Comment: If you have GIT installed, you can add to PATH system variable a path to `sh.exe`. In my case it was: `c:\Program Files\Git\bin`. Then run `sh .\script.sh` from PowerShell

Comment: This works for me like a charm in Windows 10 in 2020! Though copy/paste command not working for me as it set fixed at `ctrl-ins` and `shift-ins`

Comment: If you are using VS Code you can use the Git Bash terminal to run .sh files. Same thing as above answer but staying within VS Code

Answer (score 66):

The most common way to run a [**.sh**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) file is using the **sh** command ([GIT BASH](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-bash)):

```
C:\>sh my-script-test.sh
```

other good option is installing [**CygWin**](https://www.cygwin.com/)

in `Windows` the `home` is located in:

```
C:\cygwin64\home\[user]
```

for example i execute my `my-script-test.sh` file using the [**bash**](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_bash.htm) command as:

```
jorgesys@INT024P ~$ bash /home/[user]/my-script-test.sh
```

Comment: Unless you've taken special measures to get it, you're not going to have an `sh` command on Windows.

Comment: Ok -1 , Do you mean that i have to add a tutorial to have access to sh from the command line???

Comment: Your answer is presented as if you expect to be able to type `sh` on an arbitrary Windows command prompt and have it work.

Comment: msys2 is a good place to get the sh command. Check out https://github.com/userzimmermann/MSYS2-cmd if you want to use it with cmd

Comment: Bash, and the `sh` command, is installed with Git4Windows if you select the 'Install Bash' install option.

Comment: this doesn't directly work on command prompt but works on git bash as Joel Ellis said

Answer (score 16):

you can use also cmder

> Cmder is a software package created out of pure frustration over the absence of nice console emulators on Windows. It is based on amazing software, and spiced up with the Monokai color scheme and a custom prompt layout, looking sexy from the start

[image: Screenshot]

[cmder.app](http://cmder.app/)

Comment: Though it seems to come with an optional add-on pack which includes common Unix shell commands, the base package seems to be just a replacement for `cmd`.

Answer (score 10):

Install the `GitBash` tool in the Windows OS. Set the below `Path` in the environment variables of System for the Git installation.

> <Program Files in C:\>\Git\bin

> <Program Files in C:\>\Git\usr\bin

Type '**sh**' in `cmd` window to redirect into Bourne shell and run your commands in terminal.

Comment: Git Bash comes with [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

Answer (score 8):

just install git and by "bash <name.sh>" run your .sh file.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows 10 Anniversary Update, it's even easier to run shell commands in/with bash on ubuntu on windows

I was trying to set my region for my x-wrt r7000 netgear router, I found the following worked for me, using bash on ubuntu on windows, you do have to enable subsystem found in windows features, and dev mode on

```
ssh admin@192.168.1.1 < /mnt/c/ccode-eu.sh
```

Comment: May run. But it is a completely different environment.

Answer (score 5):

New feature in Windows - run bash on ubuntu on windows - available in Windows 10 "Insiders" builds after the Build conference:

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/

Comment: Cool, but how do you run a `sh` file with `bash`? If I try to do it, the window just flashes and disappears. If I drag&drop the file into an opened bash window, it says that the path wasn't found (because it uses a different convention).

Comment: Is it possible nowadays run an .sh file on Windows? I can not try it now but I'm interested in.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but there is a guide by Microsoft on how to run sh on windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Comment: @m93a In an Ubuntu terminal window, `bash path/to/script` runs the script. There is certainly also `sh` in Ubuntu. If the script has a proper shebang and permissions, simply `path/to/script` will run it with the rnterpreter specified in the shebang.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I used this batch file, but it does require CygWin installed (64-bit as shown). 
Just associate the file type .SH with this batchfile (ExecSH.BAT in my case) and you can double-click on the .SH and it runs.

```
@echo off
setlocal

if not exist "%~dpn1.sh" echo Script "%~dpn1.sh" not found & goto :eof

set _CYGBIN=C:\cygwin64\bin
if not exist "%_CYGBIN%" echo Couldn't find Cygwin at "%_CYGBIN%" & goto :eof

:: Resolve ___.sh to /cygdrive based *nix path and store in %_CYGSCRIPT%
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('%_CYGBIN%\cygpath.exe "%~dpn1.sh"') do set _CYGSCRIPT=%%A
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('%_CYGBIN%\cygpath.exe "%CD%"') do set _CYGPATH=%%A

:: Throw away temporary env vars and invoke script, passing any args that were passed to us
endlocal & %_CYGBIN%\mintty.exe -e /bin/bash -l -c 'cd %_CYGPATH%;  %_CYGSCRIPT% %*'
```

Based on [this](http://blog.dotsmart.net/2011/01/27/executing-cygwin-bash-scripts-on-windows) original work.

Answer (score 4):

I use Windows 10 Bash shell aka Linux Subsystem aka Ubuntu in Windows 10 as guided [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/265900/everything-you-can-do-with-windows-10s-new-bash-shell/)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `cd`ing to the root directory where your `.sh` is located in order to execute it from there, instead of writing down a path to the file as you showed in your question?

Like so:

```
$ cd app/build
$ build.sh
```