# Running Bash Scripts and chaining commands in Powershell

Tags: node.js, bash, powershell, npm

I am having trouble running this repository on Windows because from what I can see, it is heavily developed on a Unix environment.

https://github.com/gocardless/splash-pages

From the [package.json](https://github.com/gocardless/splash-pages/blob/dev/package.json), I am trying to run the script `npm run build-production` but it wouldn't work since it is dependent on a [bash file](https://github.com/gocardless/splash-pages/blob/dev/script/build).

*This is the given command:*

`"build-production": "TARGET=https://gocardless.com ./script/build"`

I tried different variation of it on windows, namely

1. `"build-production": "set TARGET=https://gocardless.com ./script/build"`

**Source:** [How can i set NODE_ENV=production in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249830/how-can-i-set-node-env-production-in-windows)

2. `"build-production": "set TARGET=https://gocardless.com; sh ./script/build"`

**Source:** https://superuser.com/questions/612409/how-do-i-run-multiple-commands-on-one-line-in-powershell

3. `"build-production": "set TARGET=https://gocardless.com&&sh ./script/build"`

**Source:** [How to run .sh on Windows Command Prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522789/how-to-run-sh-on-windows-command-prompt)

Question: How can I get this repo up and running on Windows?

Comment: superuser.com may be more appropriate, as this is a question about how to *run* a program, rather than how to *write* a program.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your Q, but generally, Windows and Linux code don't mix. You can use a mini-linux system link `mingw` on Windows to build a lot of linux software to work on Windows. But first, you should check the support team for the software in question to see if they have a procedure already defined OR if they think it is even possible. AND sorry, but you only need to say "I have tried these 3 things that didn't work, including the `Source:` in-line only makes your Q harder to read. (Maybe move them to the bottom). Good luck.

Comment: You certainly did not explore *all* the answers in the questions you link to.  If you don't have `sh` on your system, setting a variable using `set` works fine, but obviously only solves that part of the question. But the duplicate has answers for how to solve this specifically in PowerShell.