# How can I run a visible desktop application on windows 7 from salt-master

Tags: windows-7, git-bash, salt-stack

I want to run an application on Windows 7, and have it be visible from a salt-master.

My master and minion both have Boron 2016.3.1 on them.

For example, if I wanted to use file.managed to move a `test.txt` file to my desktop on my windows 7 minion, and I wanted to open it on the visible desktop, is there a way to do that.

Initially I assumed that just running the process via `cmd.run` would work, but that hasn't worked.  And [here's a feature request for this](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/4834).

I thought that maybe, if I installed git bash, and has a bash script that ran notepad it would work, but when I try using a state similar to below:

**init.sls**

```
startnotepad:
  cmd.run:
    - name: script.sh
    - cwd: c:\users\myuser\desktop
```

It doesn't work either.  It doesn't run the script at all, and just hangs.

However, when I just run the script from the local machine, it works fine.  The script is simply.

**c:\users\myuser\desktop\script.sh**

```
notepad test.txt
```

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but any help is appreciated.

---

**EDIT 1**

This question isn't specifically about how to do this with a script.  I'm interested in any way it's possible through salt.  After asking some questions on their IRC, I've gotten information on it maybe being possible through the salt.modules.win_service.config.  The [svc_type](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.win_service.html#salt.modules.win_service.config) specifically, but I have no idea how to use this, and everything I've tried has failed.

---

**EDIT2**

I found [this email chain](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/salt-users/fl1B4bCG-Nk), where it looks like someone was able to implement this.  They said they "tried Allow interaction with the desktop option", but I have no idea how to implement that.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Unless you install ubuntu for windows (beta function in winodws 10), Win7 doesn't recognise file with  `.sh` . The script can only be `.cmd` ,`.bat`  or `.ps?`(powershell).  The other options is Cygwin,  but all your program must be specify `PATH` correctly otherwise it can't find your program. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522789/how-to-run-sh-on-windows-command-prompt

Comment: I believe when I installed git bash, it added bash to the PATH.  I do know that right now if I double click on the .sh script, it runs correctly, and if I open a windows terminal, and run the .sh script it also works.