# Execute shell script on remote windows server without any third party installation

Tags: java, windows

I want to execute shell script on remote windows server through java code without any server setup and installations like SSH. My script file is already there on server. I just want to execute it on server cmd from my machine. Any possible solution?

Comment: mount the drive?

Comment: `net start` can handle remote services etc. but allowing any remote computer on your network to execute any script on any other computer out-of-the-box would be a serious security risk.

Answer (score 0):

According to definition of shell script from wiki:

"*A shell script is a computer program designed to be run by the **Unix** shell*"

Taking into consideration that you want to run a shell script on a windows server it will simply not work. I would suggest you to use some kind of environment as it is provided by **cygwin** or any other alternatives.

You can also check the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522789/how-to-run-sh-on-windows-command-prompt).

Comment: what is powershell ?

Comment: **powershell** - command-line shell designed especially for system administrators of windows. It is built on top of the .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR) and the .NET Framework.

In other words its a special shell on windows. You can read official documentation to find more. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/getting-started-with-windows-powershell?view=powershell-5.1)