# How to print from Git Bash terminal?

Tags: windows, bash, git, printing, terminal

While using git bash terminal, I can't print a pdf file. In fact I can't print anything. I am using correct file name and I've tried typing:

`lp file.pdf`

but I get bash: 
`lp: command not found`

I get same promt when trying to print anything using `lp` command.

How do you print from git bash terminal?

Comment: Redirect output to a file. Open it in wordpad and print.

Answer (score 3):

Git bash is an emulated bash. The standard programs available on most Linux distributions are not available there.

Comment: Vaguely related with more background: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26523241/874188

Answer (score 0):

Windows programs are available. You can run them, but you'll have to make sure all the details are set up, and sometimes they don't like the environment.

For example, both `notepad` and wordpad (`write`) should be able to use the `/p` and/or `/pt` options, but you may have trouble getting it to find the file.

```
write tst
```

will open the file in wordpad, and

```
write /p tst
```

is *supposed* to print it, assumedly to the default printer, though my config seems admin-locked to something stupid.

Maybe that will help. Good luck.