# How to execute this command line from linux in windows

Tags: linux, windows

as I said in the title, I'm using windows as my OS, but when I read a tutorial in github repository, they give the step to try the demo using this command:

```
1. $ cd testFolder
2. $ wget somelink.tar.gz
3. $ tar -zxvf demo_data.tar.gz
4. $ cp demo_data/00_data.sh .
5. $ cp demo_data/Config.py .
6. $ bash 00_data.sh
7. $ python 01_run.py
```

for line 1 until 3 I can do it in windows since:

1. in line 1, basically we can do it the same since `cd` means to open a folder that we want
2. line 2, is to clone the repository
3. line 3, I think it to unzip the downloaded file, and I can do it manually in windows, it's good if you can give a command line for this in windows

but for line 4-7 I'm confused as how I can trigger it in windows, can someone help me for this?

Comment: It's clear the demo was meant to run on Linux. You won't even have the bash shell, so that won't work. Even if you could end up running it, it probably won't work.

Comment: You can install https://www.cygwin.com

Comment: why the `python` tag. Don't spam tags.

Comment: Install and run under WSL

Comment: See https://batsh.org/ . Good luck.

Comment: What about GitBash?

Answer (score 0):

`line4` and `line5` copy the file `00_data.sh` and `Config.py` to the current directory `testfolder` and should work on windows

To use the bash command in `line6` should help this [How to run .sh on Windows Command Prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522789/how-to-run-sh-on-windows-command-prompt)

`line7` call the `01_run.py` file with python and should work on windows