# Git hook on bash to check prefix

Tags: git, bash, github, git-bash, githooks

I need some help with a bash script that automatically add prefix in commit -m message ,it's not a server side ,just repo, i need to add message "User:..." , and if a user type commit message name for example "Jhon" , it will be User:Jhon . Maybe who can help to write a script for it ?

Comment: Literally [the first result](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) from Google...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the default comments in the git commit message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966714/how-can-i-change-the-default-comments-in-the-git-commit-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Here's what I would do.

---

1. Write a script (e.g. `prefix_commit.sh`) that looks like this:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash
   git commit -m User:"$1"
   ```

   **Note:**

   - Using `git commit -m "User:$1"` will also work here.

---

2. Make the script executable (you only need to do this once):

   ```sh
   $ chmod +x ./prefix_commit.sh
   ```

   ---
3. Call the script from the command line and pass your commit message like so:

   ```sh
   $ ./prefix_commit.sh 'Sample commit message'
   ```

   **Note:**

   - Be sure to use *single quotes* around your commit message if you plan on writing messages with multiple words.

---

---

**Passing arguments to a bash script**

- Arguments can be received in a bash script or function like so:

  ```sh
  $1 # first argument
  $2 # second argument
  $3 # third argument

  ### $4, $5, $6, $7 ... etc
  ```

  ---
- So let's say I have a script that's called `echo_my_args.sh` that echoes out three arguments:

  ```sh
  #!/bin/bash
  echo $1
  echo $2
  echo $3
  ```

  ---
- I can pass three arguments to the script and see them echoed out:

  ```sh
  $ ./echo_my_args.sh 'my first arg' 'my second arg' 'my third arg'
  my first arg
  my second arg
  my third arg
  ```

  ---
- Note here again that the argument must use *single quotes* if it has multiple words. There is no need for single quotes if you pass a single word argument:

  ```sh
  $ ./echo_my_args.sh first second third
  first
  second
  third
  ```

  ---
- Here's some more information about how to [pass arguments to a bash script](https://www.lifewire.com/pass-arguments-to-bash-script-2200571).

Comment: Thanks , it works!! maybe you can explain what are "$1" is do ?

Comment: amazing! Thank you very much, Dan! now it's clear for me, finally i begin to understand a little bit how it works :)

Comment: Not a problem - I'm glad it helped! Bash scripting is a lot of fun.

Comment: Dan , look , now i try to write a script , to check my prefix , if prefix = User:foo, allow commit , if prefix is something else , deny. and now then i commiting my script do nothing :(  my code is : 
#!/bin/sh
MSG_empty="--- You must give a meaningful comment for commits. Thanks! ---\n END \n"
MSG_prefix="--- You must prefix your checkins with one of the following - User: or Name:
echo -e $MSG_empty > /dev/stderr
# Make sure that the log message contains prefix.
grep -P "^(User|Name):[ \t]+.{2,}" > /dev/null || exit 1
# All checks passed, so allow the commit
exit 0

Comment: @АндрейКа I can have a look at this later today after work if that's ok

Comment: Ye sure ,Dan,thanks for reply and help!  if you don't understand what i whrote in comments , maybe i can send to you code in another social network? e.g mail or skype ?

Comment: You could make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and link it here - It sounds like you want to make a bash script that confirms that a commit message has a prefix, right? Does that mean that you want to type a prefix into your commit message? You could run a script that asks the user to choose one of the prefixes - here's an example - https://gist.github.com/dankreiger/8352fdf9ad8305742b97e26b3d7240ea

Comment: hi again, Dan , now i want to write a script that checks to see if there is a word that should be in the commit message, for example if i write git commit -m "updated foo" and if word updated not in commit message commit will be stopped with an error message: please insert a word(updated) , but if word updated are present in commit -m message commit will pass. The problem is that i don't know how to make so that the script would check up my message which I transfer, i try to use git log -1 HEAD --pretty=format:%s , but it will check just my last commit.

Comment: My biggest problem is that i can't understand how it works :(, although I've read about it a lot, my most important task for now is to make the script who read my commit -m message word and if it has my word(in sample it is a "updated" it will pass the commit, If not, then not allowed.

Comment: If you want a script that requires a word, you could try something like [this](https://gist.github.com/dankreiger/3482ac9f1f4c13357d5cb693058577b5) - this one requires the word 'updated'

Comment: Yesss!!! This is exactly what what i need!! and last question is how to make  that the script does not allow the commit if there is no word "updated", and if there is it pass commit. something like this : https://gist.github.com/Zorro55/981f1c70b437e6ecd0f2628a8a69701f

Comment: The script I wrote does that, right? If the commit doesn't contain the word 'updated', it exits the script. If it does, it executes the `git commit` - here's a [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ekl2g211ogpowe/sample_bash.mov?dl=0)

Comment: Dan! finally it works!!!! thanks a lot!! you really very friendly and helpful, i glad that there are such wonderful people like you ,  who are ready to help!

Comment: if i use a Windows i don't need execute chmod +x ./prefix_commit.sh command yes? i just copy paste prefix_commit path and execute script yes? like :  '/c/Users/Andrejka/Desktop/Git Test/.git/hooks/prefix_commit'

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :) I don't have windows, so I'm not sure if it's necessary on windows - I think in PowerShell all you have to do is `sh` followed by the path to your script. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098786/run-bash-script-from-windows-powershell) is hopefully helpful.

Comment: yes , i use cygwin64, its same, like linux :) how many years you working with shell scripting?

Comment: Cool! I guess I've been coding since 2015 - I'm in the terminal all the time when I'm coding, so I've found writing shell scripts to be very useful :)

Comment: Dan , hi again , i install ubuntu and now try to run hook from it , then i run the hook , i get an: Permission denied error , maybe you know what happend? =/

Comment: @АндрейКа I'm 99% sure that you need to `chmod +x ./your_file.sh` or `sudo chmod +x ./your_file.sh` - the location of a shell script always needs to be made executable, so when you use a new location, you need to run `chmod +x` on the file in that location.

Comment: i try but i get chmod: cannot access './your_file.sh': No such file or directory. 
my scripts full path is : '/home/andrejka/Desktop/Git Test/.git/hooks/prefix-commit' , i try to: andrejka@root:~/Desktop/Git Test$ sudo chmod +x ./home/andrejka/Desktop/Git Test/.git/hooks/prefix-commit

Comment: now i set chmod and try to check git status and recieve this : andrejka@root:~/Desktop/Git Test$ git status
fatal: unable to read 540505093e91a57d13e094118cdb8bcd75632a7a

Comment: i don't know how to run this script now , i set chmod -x secessfully

Comment: That is strange. The script is just doing a `git commit` and nothing else. Would you be able to start the project in a new directory and run the script there? I don't know why you are receiving this error.

Comment: i found a solution , Den thanks for chmod!! it works not and it linux , the problem is be this ! ::: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920416/configure-bin-shm-bad-interpreter

Comment: i just type a sed -i 's/\r//' prefix-commit.sh and it start to work!!:)

Comment: Den , sorry again , but i have another same question:) Maybe you know how to make my hook automatic executable if i just type msg: git commit -m "my message" in console and if in my message aren't word "updated" , this commit has been rejected. it something like your first script with updated word , but it need to be auto executeble if i type git commit -m in console. is it passable ?

Comment: I would read up about [git hooks](http://githooks.com/) if you want to set a hook when you commit. I haven't done this before, so I'd have to learn it. You could also set a bash function that executes the script for you. Later I can try to explain this option if you're interested. However, I need to learn about making hooks if that's what you're after.

Comment: Great to hear  :)