# Powershell Redirecting standard output to file from git-bash.exe

Tags: powershell, git-bash

Ive got a very basic powershell script which uses `Start-Process` to start another .sh script, this is working and the scripts do execute but what I need is to be able to capture the output of the called script.

Content of the scripts is below:

main.ps1

```
Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe' -ArgumentList '-- C:\test\sub.sh' -Wait -RedirectStandardOutput output.txt
```

sub.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

The sub.sh launches and prints out `Hello World` in its own console, but I really need the output to either go to the calling powershell scripts console window, or to a file. The file I specify in the `-RedirectStandardOutput` parameter is created, but is empty.

How can I get the sh script to print to standard out to the calling script?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git-bash is in a different world than powershell so you can not directly redirect output or use -RedirectStandardOutput.

As you supposed, you can use an temporary file but the trick is to use internal bash operand ">" to redirect output to the file from bash process :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello from bash World" > /c/test/tempFile.txt
```

Then call it from powershell, you might hide the window also :

```
Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe' -ArgumentList C:\test\sub.sh -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden

$s = Get-Content c:\test\tempFile.txt
Write-Host "s=$s"
Remove-Item c:\test\tempFile.txt
```

Note : You have to specifilly fully qualified path.

Another option might be using Windows 10 own bash interpreter : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44359679/11867971

Answer (score 2):

As written in sub.sh, the program to execute sh files is /bin/bash, not git-bash.exe.

```bsh
$output = & 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe' C:\test\sub.sh
$output
Hello World
```

Comment: `usr\bin\bash.exe` doesn't appear to work, it gives me all kinds of errors (`bash: cut: command not found`, `Permission denied`, etc.). However, `bin\bash.exe` works perfectly - thanks!